# Swift and Stack smashing protection

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, security

How to enable Stack Smashing Protection in pure swift application?

I did try to put "-fstack-protector-all" flag to Other C++ Flags under project build settings tab in xCode, but is seems that, this flag is unused or have no impact on builded application.

To verifie build I'm using `otool -Iv AppBinary | grep stack`.

Comment: Did you got the answer to this question

Comment: No. I haven't. To fulfill client requirements I added UIView as Objective-C class. This create umbrella headers to objective-c and project was compiled as mixed Swift-Obj-c project (not pure swift project).
This view wasn't used any ware... It just was.

Comment: Thanks for your input...

Comment: Check my answer, hope it may help

Comment: I did the same as you - a C-flag setting.  I used radare2's toolset to verify if it was enabled.  `rabin2 -I <exec file NOT app bundle>| grep -E 'pic|bits|arch|canary'`

btw - when I wrote a small C app to prove this was working, I had created only one Struct. This had  NO char arrays inside.  In this case, you see zero stack guard code in the asm code even if Smashing Smashing is enabled.

Comment: @rustyMagnet can you or (anyone else) provide instructions or a link to a proj that will cause this flag to work? I have tried it on a brand new swift app using XCode template, adding objc file and bridging header and still doesnt produce the protector flag in binary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also facing this in my 100% Swift project.

Whenever I added `-fstack-protector-all` to the "Other C-Flags" Build Settings the flags did not show up in the binary as described in the other comments.

[image]

What I did was to create an Objective-C Class…

```
// DummyClassForSSP.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface DummyClassForSSP : NSObject
+ (void)dummyCallSoFlagsShowUpInIPA;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

… added a dummy implementation …

```
// DummyClassForSSP.m
#import "DummyClassForSSP.h"

@implementation DummyClassForSSP

+ (void)dummyCallSoFlagsShowUpInIPA {}

@end
```

… and called it from my AppDelegate.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
....
DummyClassForSSP.dummyCallSoFlagsShowUpInIPA()
...
}
```

After that the flags showed up as described.

Comment: This solution worked for me as well but I have one question why Objective-C Class required here and why it is not working without Objective-C Class?

Answer (score 13):

In Swift, Stack smashing is enabled by default one only need to add the "-fstack-protector-all" flag under build settings in objective-c applications.

**How to check if stack smashing is enabled.**
Run the otool command and presence of `stack_chk_guard` and `stack_chk_fail` means the code is stack smashing protected.

```
$ otool -Iv <appname>|grep stack
0x0013dfg   520 ___stack_chk_fail
0x001d009   521 ___stack_chk_guard
0x001fd345   520 ___stack_chk_fail
0x000000010087efd   513 ___stack_chk_fail
0x0000000100098hf3 514 ___stack_chk_guard
0x00000001000897gfr   513 ___stack_chk_fail
```

Comment: i exported ipa using adhoc signing. I grab the binary in it. I ran otool and the result nicely showed. But this not happens for ipa using appstore signing. Is it normal?

Comment: Exactly where in build settings we have to set "-fstack-protector-all"

Comment: Not seeing it enabled by default. Created the Single View template app in XCode, built and exported ad hoc and no stack protector flag was there

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but as it might be helpful for other's seeking advice:
Joe's answer is not correct.
-fstack-protector-all is a flag on the GCC compiler. (Documentation here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html)

For swift applications, the GCC compiler is not involved here. Instead it's the swiftc compiler with different options and settings. Alas, I don't know of comparable options for the latter one.

Adding an objective-c class to the project as @btype suggests, is not helping your swift sourcecode, as it only affects the Obj-C and C code.
But if you use 3rd party libraries written in Obj-C it's still a valuable setting. But make sure, you set this flag on the right target, if 3rd party libraries are embedded as separate targets.

Cheers, Chris

Comment: "you set this flag on the right target" what is the flag you are taking about ? And where we need to set the flag ? Please explain bit detail & screen shots improve the answer to get more upvotes

Comment: @ArshadShaik did you got the solution where we need to set the flag.