# How to use otool to check for whether Stack Smashing is enabled or not?

Tags: xcode, otool

I see many answers, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43554731/3003927), and [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86355) on the internet says to use `otool` command to check for `stack_chk_guard` and `stack_chk_fail` on the project.

The problem is, I don't know to which *file* the otool must be applied. On a [source](http://iosbrain.com/blog/2017/01/07/the-heartbreak-of-the-xcode-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-xxx-linker-message/#more-7), they say this `otool` is to be applied on a file with extension `.a`, which is a library. But I don't know how that can be applied to my situation where I want to check the *whole* project, not just a library. And I tried to find any file within my project with `.a` extension, and I found none. I've tried to run `otool` against `.app`, `.framework`, `.xcarchive`, and `.ipa`, all failed.

Can somebody help? Please be elaborate if necessary, because I never use `otool` before, and documentations on the internet doesn't help at all when it comes to describe what files can be checked by `otool`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After a hairpulling search session, I found out that the file you're supposedly supply to otool is inside the `.app` directory. Yes, the `.app` is a directory, not a file.

So this is how to do it:

- build your project first, which will create a `.app` file.
- in the Xcode project navigator (left panel side), filter for `.app` name on bottom.
- right click on the `.app` file, select "show in finder".
- open a terminal window.
- type `cd` and then drag the `.app` directory to the terminal. It will populate the path.
- type `otool -Iv Your_App_Binary_Name | grep stack`

This `Your_App_Binary_Name` bits can make you confused, but don't be. Just note what is the name of your `.app` directory. For example, if the directory is `MyApp.app`, then your binary should be `MyApp` without extension, inside the `MyApp.app` directory. If you see the file using finder (right click on the `.app` and select "show package contents"), you'll see the type of the binary file is UNIX executable.

(Don't forget, if your app name contains spaces, you need to use backslash to escape the space. For example, if your app name is "My Holy App", then the directory is `My\ Holy\ App.app` and the app binary is `My\ Holy\ App`)

So your terminal will look like this for target named "My App":

```
$ cd ......./Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app
$ otool -Iv MyApp | grep stack
0x00000001000c17bc 19966 ___stack_chk_fail
0x00000001000d8268 19967 ___stack_chk_guard
0x00000001000d8d18 19966 ___stack_chk_fail
```

or in case your target has spaces like "My Holy App":

```
$ cd ......./Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/My\ Holy\ App.app
$ otool -Iv My\ Holy\ App | grep stack
0x00000001000c17bc 19966 ___stack_chk_fail
0x00000001000d8268 19967 ___stack_chk_guard
0x00000001000d8d18 19966 ___stack_chk_fail
```

**EDIT:** user mnemonic23 stated that if you compile the IPA with rebuild from bitcode, the result of otool won't show the result above. You have to compile the IPA without rebuild from bitcode.

Comment: This works exactly as described. Thank you for putting this together.

Comment: i've found out that it only works to adhoc deployment, not appstore/release mode. am I right?

Comment: i exported adhoc ipa, the result showed. but not for ipa exported for appstore. is it normal?

Comment: @mnemonic23 in my case, I exported for enterprise distribution too, and it shows the result for me. I still haven't tried for appstore case.

Comment: i have confirmed that bitcode causing the result not showing too. So i uncheck "include bitcode" when exporting and it worked.

Comment: @mnemonic23 oh I see! I never include bitcode when compiling IPA, so that was never the problem for me. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: after enable -fstack-protector-all got the same result in order as above, is that mean stack canary enabled?

Comment: @iosDev yes, you're on the right path.