# How to enable Stack Smashing Protection in IOS swift application?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

I did try to put `"-fstack-protector-all"` flag to other C++ Flags under project build settings tab in `xCode`, but it seems that, this flag is unused or have no impact on the builded application.

To verify build I'm using `otool -Iv AppBinary | grep stack`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift and Stack smashing protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564924/swift-and-stack-smashing-protection)

Answer (score 0):

`-fstack-protector-all` is a flag on the GCC compiler.
(Documentation [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html))

As you state "swift application" in the topic, the GCC compiler is not involved here. Instead it's the swiftc compiler with different options and settings.
Alas, I don't know of comparable options for the latter one.