# Swift and Stack smashing protection not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, security

How to enable Stack Smashing Protection in the swift application?

I did try to put "-fstack-protector-all" flag to Other C Flags under project build settings tab in xCode, but is seems that, this flag is unused or have no impact on builded application.

To verifie build I'm using otool -Iv AppBinary | grep stack
[image]

Run the otool command and no presence of stack_chk_guard and stack_chk_fail.
I tried for both build App.app file and Development signing file,no working.
What additional setting need to add in my Xcode swift app?

Comment: any idea for that?

Comment: I am facing the same issue in my swift project, Have you find any solution? As I know there is no need to enable Stack Smashing Protection in swift project because it is default enabled, only in Objective -C we have to put "-fstack-protector-all" flag to Other C Flags under project build settings tab.

Comment: I add "-fstack-protector-all" flag to Other C Flags,but not wrorking

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60151692/1884701). It worked for me.
As per this Solution you have to do below steps-

1. Add Objective-C Class in you Swift project.
2. Add "-fstack-protector-all" flag to Other C Flags and Other C++ Flags
3. Than execute **otool -Iv AppBinaryPath | grep stack** command on Terminal. it will show result like bello-

___stack_chk_fail

___stack_chk_guard